# Bash Scripting, Android, forward a specific port incoming on tun0 to wlan0 to Local PC

Tags: android, bash, network-programming, portforwarding

I have this script running on boot (as root) on my phone and cycling on a timer to make my wifi hotspot send data through a PIA VPN(tun0). PIA will assign a single port allowed to be used for port forwarding and I now want to forward that assigned port to a tethered PC which is connected to the wifi hotspot (wlan0). The PC's local IP address is 192.168.1.252 (hotspot assigned) and the port number is 40212 (PIA assigned). Is there a way to add that routing to this script?

Additional Info:

```
$ netcfg
wlan0 UP 192.168.1.1/24 
lo    UP 127.0.0.1/8 
tun0  UP 10.100.1.6/30
rmnet UP xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx #Didn't want phone's external(?) IP online.
```

Script:

```
while sleep 30; do
iptables -t filter -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 8.8.8.8
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup 61
ip route add default dev tun0 scope link table 61
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 scope link table 61
ip route add broadcast 255.255.255.255 dev wlan0 scope link table 61
```